# How to make a jQuery object undraggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to modify the [jQuery-ui Photo Manager demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager) so that the images in the Trash are undraggable but I'm unable to do so.  I've changed the demo so that the Gallery is no longer droppable, but the items in the Trash still follow my cursor if I mousedown.  Of course, they they revert back because they have nowhere to go, but is there a way to make them ignore the mousedown to begin with?

Answer (score 4):

see http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-cancel

In the case of the demo, this line:

```
    cancel: 'a.ui-icon',// clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
```

Needs to change to:

```
    cancel: 'a.ui-icon, #trash li', // add selector for items in trash
```

<strike>I haven't tested, but it should work</strike>

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/umefa)

Is that what you want? Also added `#trash .gallery li img {cursor: default;}` to the css.

Comment: See my demonstration. How is that not what he wanted?

Comment: It sure looks like what he wanted. I can't move any of the things that I've dragged into the circular file.

Comment: Hi ghoppe, thanks for the info and for explaining how the "cancel" option works.  Unfortunately in my app it didn't work, but I worked around it by setting elt.draggable({containment: [0, 0, 0, 0]}) to commandeer the draggable functionality on that element.

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of this would do it;

```
.droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped)
            .detach()
            .css('left', 'initial')
            .css('top', 'initial')
            .appendTo(droppedOn);
        $(dropped).draggable( 'disable' );
    }
});
```

The mentioned demo from @ghoppe, and link to jquery documentation has gone obsolete or offline. Hence this answer to this very old post, after having found a solution, so I won't have to google it fruitlessly again.